# Python Dictionaries Print Options

Tags: python, dictionary

Code is from Learn Python The Hard Way Exercise 39. Please see my question below the first set of codes.

```
# create a mapping of state to abbreviation
states = {
    'Oregon': 'OR',
    'Florida': 'FL',
    'California': 'CA',
    'New York': 'NY',
    'Michigan': 'MI'
}

# create a basic set of states and some cities in them
cities = {
    'CA': 'San Francisco',
    'MI': 'Detroit',
    'FL': 'Jacksonville'
}

# do it by using the state then cities dict
print '-' * 10
print "Michigan has: ", cities[states['Michigan']]
print "Florida has: ", cities[states['Florida']]
```

Why print it out the above way, when you simply can do it like below?

```
print '-' * 10
print "Michigan has: ", cities['MI']
print "Florida has: ", cities['FL']
```

I am wondering if I am missing something important here. Is it for learning purpose only? If so, what am I exactly learning there? Please clarify.

Comment: It's just an example of what you can do. Out of context there is no actual reason for doing this, but it shows that you can use a dynamic value (from another dict here) as key of a dictionary

Comment: You happened to know that the abbreviation for Michigan is 'MI'. The original code does not have that assumption of knowledge: using it only  requires knowing the name of the state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is more general:

```
>>> for state in ('Michigan', 'Florida'):
...    print '%s has: %s' % (state, cities[states[state]])
...
```

The second approach does not generalize in this manner since all of sudden you need to know state codes a priori.

Comment: Thank you. Maketh sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed do it either way, provided you know both the state's name and its abbreviation. But the way presented in the book could easily be adapted in useful ways, e.g.

```
for state, abbreviation in states.items():
    if abbreviation in cities:
        print state, "has: ", cities[abbreviation]
```

to get a list of the state-city pairs.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at pretty print standard lib:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html